# PHP curl returns odd result

Tags: php, curl

I'm using PHP CURL to scrape a `class` from a webpage and display it on my site.

In the script below, I'm trying to get the content from the class `assets-explorer-cost-text` on the page https://www.roblox.com/users/261/inventory/#!/hats to display on my website.

However, I'm being provided with the result `{{item.Product.PriceInRobux | abbreviate : 1}}` instead of `750`
Here's proof that the result should be 750
[image]

```
<?php
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.roblox.com/users/261/inventory/#!/hats");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$html = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$DOM = new DOMDocument();
$DOM->loadHTML($html);
$finder = new DomXPath($DOM);
$classname = 'assets-explorer-cost-text';
$nodes = $finder->query("//*[contains(@class, '$classname')]"); 
$printedtext = $nodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
echo "<p>${printedtext}</p>";
?>
```

Comment: Curl only gets the source code of the page. It doesn't process any JavaScript on that page. The source code is just a template, so that's what you are actually getting. Maybe use the network inspector to look at where the data is actually coming from and get that instead. In fact, this is very likely to be much easier to parse than the raw HTML.

Comment: From looking at the page's source through `view-source:` rather than Inspect Element, it does indeed seem like the class `assets-explorer-cost-text` is processed using Javascript

Comment: @Chris It is easier to understand if you refer to the HTML of a page as "markup" or similar, not as "source code". People often confuse that with `cURL` fetching some PHP code that generates the HTML markup which is in interpretation we have to fight against all the time...

Comment: @arkascha Good point. I'm slightly too late to edit my comment but I'll bear that in mind next time.